# Django: copy and update a queryset

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
   a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="bs")
```

then I have a function where I create a new record of object `A` and I would like to copy all the related records of `B`

I have done something such as

```
def foo(new_a, old_a):
    old_a.bs.all().update(pk=None, a=new_a)
```

but I get the following error
`ERROR - failed to write data to stream: <open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0x7f207949a150>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing something like this

```
def foo(new_a, old_a):
    old_a.bs.all().update(pk=None)
```

will try to set `pk=None` on all the `bs` for `old_a` which is not what you want.

Instead you'll want to do something like:

```
for b in old_a.bs.all():
    b.pk = None # make sure you're not overwriting the existing record
    b.a = new_a
    b.save()
```

I think you should also be able to use `bulk_create` to do this more efficiently:

```
new_bs = []
for b in old_a.bs.all():
    b.pk = None # make sure you're not overwriting the existing record
    b.a = new_a
    new_bs.append(b)

B.objects.bulk_create(new_bs)
```

Answer (score 7):

Hope that help:

```
queryset = B.objects.filter(something="a")

for element in query_set:
    a_object = A.objects.bulk_create(**element)
```

Comment: Thanks, except I have to set the id of the `new_a`